# DateTime Overflow in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, parsing

We have a Scala/Java back end that is generating the equivalent of `DateTime.MaxValue` in .NET.

I am sent the following date as a string "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z".

If I used `DateTime.TryParse("9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z", out var dateTime)`, then it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.Parameter name: value).

I didn't expect this, since I was calling **Try**Parse.  Perhaps returning false would have been more intuitive?

If I reduce the year, I can see .NET is rolling the date over to the following day, which obviously wont work on a max date/time!

```
DateTime.TryParse("9998-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z", out var dateTime);
dateTime.ToString().Dump();
```

Outputs: 01/01/9999 00:00:00

If I reduce the precision of the ms by 2, then it works:

```
DateTime.TryParse("9998-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z", out var dateTime);
dateTime.ToString().Dump();
```

Outputs: 31/12/9998 23:59:59

This really looks like a bug in .NET?  Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: `I am sent the following date as a string...` Why are you sent this string? Seems like `null` would be a better choice if there is no date or the date is unknown. That is *almost* always a better choice then using the maximum possible value.

Comment: Separate from the discussion of whether this was the right value to send to indicate "future, no end date", yes, this sounds (to me) like a bug in .NET. You should raise an issue on github - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues

Comment: It does end... just a little bit in the future :)  Agreed, but semantics aside, that is a valid date, why wont it parse as such?

Comment: Documentation for `DateTime.MaxValue` states: "The value of this constant is equivalent to 23:59:59.9999999 UTC, December 31, 9999 in the Gregorian calendar, exactly one 100-nanosecond tick before 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 10000.". So in the first example you are passing `59.999999999Z` instead of `59.9999999Z`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks, will test in .NET Core too and raise an issue if it occurs there too (which I suspect it would).

Comment: The problem is the presence of `Z`: this is considered time zone information, and so `DateTime.TryParse` attempts to convert the result to a local time, which won't fit. (This behavior is documented.) Without the `Z`, it will work. I can't immediately find an easy way to get `DateTime` to parse the string into a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` (or `Utc`). `DateTimeOffset` *will* parse it correctly, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree that this is likely the reason, but **Try**Parse shouldn't throw an exception. If the parsed value cannot correctly be represented in a DateTime value, the method should return false, this is even documented on [DateTime.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2): "except that the TryParse(String, DateTime) method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails." Clearly the conversion failed, with an exception, which is wrong according to the documentation.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: you're right, but I'm sure happy it does in this case! Otherwise, finding the reason for the failure would be damn near impossible...

Comment: Not entirely sure, if removing two of the 9's doesn't have this problem, why did having them have this problem? Is one of them more prone to time zone handling than the other? It reads more like a rounding problem to me.

Comment: But it really doesn't matter, `DateTime.TryParse` cannot handle 10.000 years into the future either, and this will also return false, the fact that it can be numerically represented is besides the fact that `DateTime` cannot represent the value.

Comment: @FCin Interesting... sounds as if .NET knows of no time after 59.9999999, but the Java world does!  I would expect the parsing logic to not increment the day for me though (although I can see why it does) and I wouldn't expect tryparse to throw.

Comment: With exactly 7 digits, the format matches .NET's own `O` format. With any other number, it does not. Using `ParseExact` gives "not valid" for the one case and "out of range" for the other. `TryParse` apparently runs into an edge case here where it fails in a way it's not supposed to.

Comment: These (and other potential rounding issues) make a good argument for not using the exact extreme upper value as the edge case for date/times, by the way (you can run into similar problems with SQL Server). How many 9s are necessary before some system will overflow even before time zone adjustments? `9999-12-31T00:00:00` really ought to be good enough, especially when interoperating... (But even that's only a stopgap, because "silent" time zone adjustments can still screw you over if the date is adjusted to 9999-12-30. Perhaps mapping anything that starts with `9999-12-31` is the sanest thing.)

Comment: There's  no bug, as @JeroenMostert suggested date format is invalid, DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,                                             DateTimeStyles.None); but indeed a issue can be raised on .net, I guess for .net core this would be a great feature for portability and liability .

Comment: @SilentTremor By your definition it's not a bug because the format is invalid.  Using the same reasoning, DateTime.TryParse("InvalidFormat", out var dateTime) must be a bug, since that doesn't throw?  Perhaps the consumer of TryParse must know that some invalid formats are validly invalid, where as some aren't?

Comment: IMHO, it is a bug.  David reported it (thanks) here:   https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32907

Answer (score 2):

You have too many nines in your string. The exception you observing is the precision issue.

Try doing the following:

```
DateTime.MaxValue.ToString("o")
```

it will result in "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999" rather than "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z", i.e. two less nines at the end.

Use `"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z"` as an input and it will parse successfully into DateTime.MaxValue.

PS: TryParse will also convert this value to your local timezone, which I assume is not somewhat you would anticipate. Use extended version instead:

```
DateTime.TryParse("9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out var dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing Min/Max/Infinity and etc. values between different platforms is a bad idea. Each platform might have its own representation of special values (not only dates). Therefore the only valid option is to pass epoch values (milliseconds options are preferable in most cases), since they are known to the both parties.

If the above is impossible for some reason then you have two **ugly** options:

1. Replace special values in your Scala/Java output with your own "encoding". For example as "MaxValue", or take your pick as your see fit. On the .Net side you will detect special values and translate them accordingly.
2. Insert some simple preprocessing into your .Net code. For example check 
   `"9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999".StartsWith("9999")`
   for max values.

Comment: You could argue the opposite to this... it's not a "special value", it's just a date in the future?

"Therefore the only valid option is to pass epoch values"
I disagree.  There's more than one valid option.  One could be to ensure we can represent this valid date (even if that means removing some precision) in .NET.  The .NET Core team have been extremely responsive and have fixed this, which I think is the correct answer to my question.

Comment: While it is nice that .NET Core will support this value, but it is still wrong to pass ISO 8601 values. It doesn't matter whether you want to call .MaxValue a special one or not: it is clear that year 9999 is not a standard "tomorrow" (for Astronomy please use different representation of dates). Different technologies should talk to each other using some agreed standards.  ISO 8601 could be one of them, if agreed on by both parties which was not the case (it is with the newest .NET Core). There is nothing wrong with my answer given that you never mentioned that you are using .NET Core.

Comment: You're right, it's not tomorrow, but it is a valid date that can be represented in ISO 8601 format!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` as argument fix it for .NET Framework

e.g. for Windows Powershell:

```
$d = [DateTime]::Parse("9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z", $null, 16)
Get-Date $d
```